# How to statically-link a complex program

Tags: linux, static, linker

In Linux, downloaded a program source and want it to be statically linked.
Have a huge Makefile there,
I

```
./configure
make
```

to compile.
prehpes it's a bit too general to ask, but how can I make the binary statically linked?

EDIT: the reason for this is wanting to make sure the binary will 
have no dependencies (or at least as few as possible), making it possible to run on any Linux based computer, even one without Internet connection, and non-updated   Linux.

Comment: Static linking is considered harmful!
http://people.redhat.com/drepper/no_static_linking.html I'm sorry, this is not a direct answer to your question, but I just wanted to point it out.

Comment: Dynamic linking has actually been shown to be harmful! https://www.helpnetsecurity.com/2022/06/10/symbiote-linux-malware/

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Most `autoconf` generated `configure` script will allow you to make a static build:

```
 ./configure --enable-static
 make
```

If that doesn't work, you may be able to pass linker flags in via `LDFLAGS`, like this:

```
 ./configure LDFLAGS=-static
```

Comment: Very good answer, unfortunately both didn't work for some reason.

Comment: From what I understand it didn't work because I was lacking the static libraries to link with.

Comment: On CentOS the packages you need to install for static linking are `glibc-static` for c and `libstdc++-static` for c++ static linking. See [this post for more info](https://www.systutorials.com/5217/how-to-statically-link-c-and-c-programs-on-linux-with-gcc/)

Comment: This answer is not fully correct. `--enable-static` flag is only for libraries, and it means "Build static-capable version of this library (maybe in addition to dynamic-capable one)". Dynamic version (enabled with `--enable-shared`) is `.so` for Linux or `.dylib` for Mac, and static version is usually `.a`.

Comment: FYI if the `LDFLAGS` method not work, add another dash ahead. `./configure LDFLAGS='--static'`. This may work for some projects, e.g. `procps`

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, you need to edit the make file and add the -static parameter to gcc during the link.

Answer (score 2):

I assume it's using gcc to compile a series of c programs, although you will have to look in the Makefile to find out.

If so, you can adjust the gcc lines in the makefile to do static linking, although depending upon the structure of the program, this may be a complex change.  Take a look at man gcc to see how this is done.

I'd be interested to know why you are statically linking.  Have you considered using prelinking instead?

You should be aware that there may be licence problems to doing this if all components are not GPL.

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot compile a static binary, I've had good results using [Statifier](http://statifier.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Excellent idea.
I had very good results with a similar product.