# How to static link Linux software that uses ./configure?

Tags: linux, gcc, configure, static-linking, omnios

I would like to compile [NRPE](ftp://ftp.fu-berlin.de/unix/network/nagios/nrpe-2.x/nrpe-2.15/nrpe-2.15.tar.gz) static, so I can copy the compiled binary to an OmniOS server, where I don't want gcc to be installed on. I would prefer to install NRPE with SSl support from a repository, but such doesn't seam to exist, so I would like to compile it myself. However the `./configure` script doesn't contain a static option it seams

```
~/nrpe-2.15# ./configure --help | grep static
~/nrpe-2.15# ./configure --help | grep share
  --datadir=DIR          read-only architecture-independent data [PREFIX/share]
  --sharedstatedir=DIR   modifiable architecture-independent data [PREFIX/com]
```

**Question**

How do I compile a program that uses `configure` statically?

Comment: It seems that this package does not support static linking...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to staticly-link a complex program](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983515/how-to-staticly-link-a-complex-program)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Try this:

```
./configure LDFLAGS="-static"
```

Comment: But I get a lot of `warning: Using 'xxx' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking`

Comment: Yes, that's true, there are some things that will be `dlopen`d at runtime. I think DNS lookups need this, for one. It's not ideal. :-(

Comment: If you are trying to static link against glibc, you can't run on OmniOS anyway, which requires the illumos libc -- glibc only works with a Linux kernel.

Comment: I'm getting `configure: error: C++ compiler cannot create executables` when I run this flag.

Comment: My error was caused by a missing package, `libstdc++-static` since the program under question was using c++. [This tutorial helped me](https://www.systutorials.com/5217/how-to-statically-link-c-and-c-programs-on-linux-with-gcc/)

Answer (score 29):

For people coming from google, I found that if you have `libtool` part of your build, you will need to:

1. `./configure CFLAGS="-static" ....`
2. `make LDFLAGS="-all-static"`

You can see that `-all-static` with `libtool --help --mode=link`

Comment: It's important here that, as shown, `LDFLAGS="-all-static"` is given _only_ to `make`, and not set at `./configure` time, because otherwise it would break the configure scripts (because only the `libtool` wrapper accepts it, compilers like `gcc` themselves do not).

Comment: Yet another reason to hate autotools. :(

Comment: Just a heads up, be sure to note the generated LDFLAGS from `configure`'s output.  You may be required to re-add any other options that are present, like `-L` to include specific library paths.